# Unable To Understand Number Theory Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand the proof to the following number theory question:

Let a > 0 and b be integers. Show that there is an integer k such that b + ka >    0. (Hint: use
well-ordering.)

This is the proof:

Suppose not. Then let S be the set of integers {−(b+ka) : k ∈ Z}, so by hypothesis S consists entirely
of nonnegative integers. By the Well-Ordering Principle, it has a smallest positive element, say, b+ka.
But then b + (k − 1)a is smaller since a > 0, contradiction.

My first question is how can b + ka be the smallest element in set S, didn't we just assume it to be non-positive so that -(b + ka) is  non-negative? Furthermore, how exactly is b + (k - 1)a smaller? Even if $a > 0$, what if say b = -10 and k was 2 and a = 5, then that would have been $0$, but if we make k = 1 then we would get -5 which is smaller than 0, but clearly does not belong to the set...

This is question 1 from this site:
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/assignments/MIT18_781S12_pset1.pdf

Again, this is the proof: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/assignments/MIT18_781S12_pset1sol.pdf

Comment: Probably a mistake, it should be "$-(b+ak)$" is the smallest element, and that contradicts that "$-(b+ak+a)$" is smaller. Yes, the latter could also be zero but then $-(b+ak+a+a)$ would be negative, another contradiction.

Comment: you wrote -(b + ak + a) shoudn't it be -(b + ak - a) because of (k - 1)?

Comment: No, if $a>0$ then $-(b+ak+a)$ is smaller than $-(b+ak)$.

Comment: @PeterFranek corrected the error in the proof.  Let me make one more remark: the presence of negation in this problem introduces an inessential complication.  The point of this exercise is to illustrate the WOP, and yet the neophyte solver spends more time micormanaging inequality signs.  Prove for yourself the following variation: let $a>0$ and $b$ any integer.  Show that the set $\{ka+b|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ has a non-positive element (negative or zero).

Comment: One more remark: rather than delve directly into a proof, try to picture the statement of the problem.  Integer sequences are easy to depict on the integer line.  Can you see what this set is?  Draw some elements of it.  Get intuition.

Comment: I think I get it now, also this is how I would prove @guest 's question: Assume the set S = {ka + b} can only be positive, by WOP let us say ka + b is smallest element, then take ka + b - a, which must be smaller, a contradiction; furthermore, if ka + b - a is non-positive we get a different contradiction, because (k - 1)a + b should be positive by assumption, thus, we have proven it must have at least one non-positive element!